# RSpec title test fails with the variable full_title, but passes with string text the variable full_title provides to the title

Tags: rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm going through [Chapter 5 of RailsTutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec%3asignup_url).

I have one test that I can't get to work no matter what I do. It passes when I put in the string the variable passes, but not when I put in the variable itself.

The error says **undefined method 'full_title'** (I couldn't find an answer after 30 min of browsing related questions after typing this up.)

Doing a superficial test, the desired content displays in the app, the title includes the full title with 'Sign up.'

Here is my code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
      before { visit signup_path }
      it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end
end
```

This is when the error says **undefined method 'full_title'**

It passes when I use this code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
      before { visit signup_path }
      it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Sign up') }
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help!
Adam

Comment: What about your `spec/support/utilities.rb` ?

Comment: I missed that. Trying it now.

Comment: Heh, I'm running into the exact same problem in chapter 5 and just Google'd to see if there was a solution. I don't know about you but my spec/support/utilities.rb file contains the function and it seems like that file isn't being auto loaded, but I'm going to have to test that.

Comment: That's strange, just restarted guard and now it's working. Oh well. Good luck with your issue ATSiem

Comment: Thanks for the help thoferon and Gerry! I got all my full_title tests working once I included the 'utilities.rb'. I TOTALLY glossed over that as it looked like the guide was referencing the exercise from the earlier chapter. Turns out it was an exact duplication of the code in two places. (Not exactly ideal, as it mentions.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make the `full_title` tests work, make sure to create `spec/support/utilities.rb` from [Listing 5.26](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec%3apretty_rspec)

I skipped it by accident since it looks exactly like a duplicate method from Chapter 3.

Comment: And as Andriy Yurchuk said, restart Guard if you're using that.

Answer (score 11):

Restarting Guard fixes the problem.

Comment: this worked for me. I had the same problem. The command to run Guard is bundle exec guard

Comment: This worked for me. Always make sure to restart Guard before doing anything else.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem, and here is how I solved it.  Make sure that the file `/spec/support/utilities.rb` has the following code:

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: Are there drawbacks to this? I prefer this solution because it reduces duplicating the code from the `ApplicationHelper` in another file

Answer (score 1):

If write: config.include ApplicationHelper 
into spec_helper.rb everything will work fine, but it that moment I don't see logic to have file utilities.rb into spec/support (everything works without it)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem... except after 20 minutes of banging my head against the wall, I finally saw what was wrong: I named the `rspec/support` folder `suppport`. No wonder `spec_helper.rb` couldn't find it. *facepalm*

Comment: I did something similar: I mistakenly created the file `rspec/requests/support/utilities.rb` because I was in the requests directory when I created the support/ directory.